# What's the first appearance of Becoming the Costume on Halloween in literature?

Tags: history-of, trope

What's the first appearance of [Becoming the Costume](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BecomingTheCostume) on Halloween in literature?

> Something turns people into whatever costume they are wearing.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55229/whats-the-first-appearance-of-becoming-the-costume-on-halloween

Comment: So this question is looking for the first appearance of the trope in *literature*, and the question on M&TV is looking for the first appearance of the trope in movies and TV?

Comment: @Null - Yes. Precisely. Should I specify the movies and tv in the other question?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary since you'll get an answer specific to movies and TV on the M&TV site. I just wanted to clarify your question on this site. Please be more careful with your questions in the future, since you invalidated an answer when you clarified this one.

Comment: @Null - True... But, that answer would have at least been valid for M&TV if it dealt with Halloween 'stead of Mardi Gras. ... But your point stands.